# Strange behaviour in viewWillAppear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, global-variables, viewwillappear

I have a TabBar Controller with some tab bar item in it.

The first time that a user tap on a tab bar item, I want that a alertview is opened, so that the user can read some little instruction tips.

I have a global variable (say CONFIG), that hold some boolean valeus (CONFIG.tip1AlreadySeen, CONFIG.tip1AllreadySeen, etc.). All these boolean values are initializated to NO.

When the user tap a tab bar item, the viewWillAppear method in its viewcontroller is executed. In this method I put a code like this one:

```
-(void) viewVillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    extern CONFIG; // <- it's not the actual code but it indicates that a global variable must be used

    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    if(CONFIG.tip1AlreadySeen == NO) {
        CONFIG.tip1AlreadySeen = YES;

        // code for showing the alertview
    }    
}
```

The strange thing is that this piece of code works perfectly in one viewcontroller but doesn't work in one another.

With some debug, I fidd out that in the another viewcontroller the code is executed but the assigment CONFIG.tipAlreadySeen = YES doesn't modify the actual value of CONFIG.tipAlreadySeen. This value is still NO. Unbelievable!!!

A little workaround was using the viewDidAppear method for changing the value:

```
-(void) viewVillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    extern CONFIG; // <- it's not the actual code but it indicates that a global variable must be used

    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    if(CONFIG.tip1AlreadySeen == NO) {
        // code for showing the alertview
    }    
}

-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    extern CONFIG;
    CONFIG.tip1AlreadySeen = YES;
}
```

...But I really did not understand what happened!!! Someone of you could explain this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Marco

Answer (score 0):

Why must this be global and not contained in the view controller itself? Just a simple `BOOL` @property on your view controller that is toggled. And, to maintain this persistent across multiple runs of your application, save out the result to NSUserDefaults, which you in turn check each time you init your view controller.

Comment: In this specific case, you're right: I didn't need a global variable. But to mantain the persistent across multiple runs of my application, I created a global object CONFIG taht is written to disk when the user quit the application (using NSKeyedArchiver).

I didn't try yet with NSUserDefault, I'll take a look.

But my question still remains: why in one viewcontroller the assignment

    CONFIG.tip1AlreadySeen = YES

and in some other viecontrollers it is not?